# getting incorrect time while converting string into date object

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am using calling this function   getFormattedTimeFromString(startTime)

```js
getFormattedTimeFromString(timeString){
    return  (new Date('1970-01-01T' + timeString + 'Z'));
  }
```

Comment: give a runable code that works and a input and an expected output. it's unclear what's consider incorrect and correct

Comment: for e.g I am passing getFormattedTimeFromString("14:00:00") and getting "Thu Jan 01 1970 19:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"  as Output

Comment: for simple to use advanced date/time manipulations http://momentjs.com/ could be the right choice

Answer (score 1):

if you are passing in `getFormattedTimeFromString("14:00:00")` and getting `Thu Jan 01 1970 19:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` as Output well then that is expected...

What do you want it to be? Maybe you want to remove the `Z`? for it to be local?

the `Thu Jan 01 1970 19:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` is just a representation in your local timezone 
while i get `Thu Jan 01 1970 15:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`
but it still being the same in UTC.

If you would do:

```
new Date(`Thu Jan 01 1970 19:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)`).toJSON()
// you get same input back
"1970-01-01T14:00:00.000Z"
```

which is still the same input

You also have diffrent method on the date object like `getUTCxxxx` if that is what u want

Comment: thanx man worked after  removing Z .but can you please tell me what problem was with Z.?

Comment: Z: a suffix which, when applied to a time, denotes a UTC offset of 00:00